# How can I crawl the two level website with scrapy framework

Tags: python, scrapy

I want crawl a website which has two level url,the first level is a muti-page list ,url like this:

- http://www.example.com/group/
- http://www.example.com/group/p2/
- http://www.example.com/group/p3/
- http://www.example.com/group/p{n}/

Page layout like this:

- List item link 1
- List item link 2
- List item link 3
- List item link 4

1,2,3,4,5 ... nextpage

and the second level is a detail page,url like this:

- http://www.example.com/group/view/1/
- http://www.example.com/group/view/2/
- http://www.example.com/group/view/3/
- http://www.example.com/group/view/{n}/

my spider code is:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders.crawl import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders.crawl import Rule
from urlparse import urljoin

class MyCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = "AnjukeCrawler"

    start_urls=[
        "http://www.example.com/group/"
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),
                               restrict_xpaths=(["//div[@class='multi-   page']/a[@class='aNxt']"])),
                               callback='parse_list_page',
                               follow=True)
    ]

    def parse_list_page(self, response):

        list_page=response.xpath("//div[@class='li-  itemmod']/div/h3/a/@href").extract()

        for item in list_page:
            yield scrapy.http.Request(self,url=urljoin(response.url,item),callback=self.parse_detail_page)


    def parse_detail_page(self,response):

        community_name=response.xpath("//dl[@class='comm-l-detail float-l']/dd")[0].extract()

        self.log(community_name,2)
```

**My question is :my parse_detail_page seem never run ,somebody can tell me why? How can I fix it?**

thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your xpath queries generate results? You can use `print` to obtain the list of items.

Comment: Yes,I've debug the code,the request has been created

Comment: @hl79-james oh, could you post crawl log? you can generate one by `scrapy crawl myspider &> output.log`. It's quite likely your request is getting filtered by dupe filter.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question then what you are looking here for is request chaining. Request chaining is when you carry over the data gathered from response1 to response2 via request:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = dict()
    item['name'] = response.xpath("...").extract_first()

    urls = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
    for url in urls:
        yield Request(url, self.parse2,
                      meta={'item':item})  # <-- this is the important bit

def prase2(self, response):
    # now lets retrieve our item generated in parse()
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['last_name'] = response.xpath("...").extract_first()
    return item
    # {'name': 'some_name', 'last_name': 'some_last_name'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never overwrite `parse` method of `CrawlSpider` because it contains core parsing logic for this type of spiders, so your `def parse(` should be `def parse_list_page(` - and that typo is your issue.

However your rule looks like overhead because of using both callback and `follow=True` just to extract links, it is better to consider using of the list of rules and rewrite your spider like this:

```
class MyCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = "AnjukeCrawler"

    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com/group/"
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='multi-page']/a[@class='aNxt']"),
             follow=True),
        Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='li-itemmod']/div/h3/a/@href"),
             callback='parse_detail_page'),
    ]

    def parse_detail_page(self, response):
        community_name = response.xpath("//dl[@class='comm-l-detail float-l']/dd")[0].extract()
        self.log(community_name, 2)
```

BTW, too many brackets in the link extractor: `restrict_xpaths=(["//div[@class='multi-   page']/a[@class='aNxt']"])`