# How force scrapy to parse second page when finished first one

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am using Scrapy version 1.5.1. I crated parser, which parse urls from main page, then parse urls from already parsed urls, etc. Scrapy works asynchronously and makes parallel connections. The problem is, that I have some logic which urls should parse first, creating sets of urls which I already visited, maximum urls to visit etc.

At first, I configure `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN=1` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=1`, but it did not help, because I think there is scheduler that cache url which will process next and then, perform it in different order.

What I need to do, is to force scrapy to process one url and wait till it is finished and then, start parsing new url, etc. Is there a way how to configure scrapy to do this?

Comment: This is a very common question and what you are looking for is called request chaining. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753743 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660978

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy merge subsite-item with site-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753743/scrapy-merge-subsite-item-with-site-item)

Comment: Well I have item, object consist of functions to parse and store urls. I pass this object over metadata of request. Right now, I process 3 domains. The output json consist of 3 domains, but visited pages are mixed. Domain 1 visited urls consist of urls from all 3 domains. The same for domain 2 and 3. I need to process first domain, then second domain and then third domain, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `yield response.follow` instead of `yield Request`: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.follow